# How to overwrite evil-motion-state-map in Doom Emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to override *L* in `evil-motion-state-map` (`evil-window-bottom`) so my custom binding takes precedence in treemacs. However, this doesn't seem to work:

```
; my-mode.el
(map! :after evil-mode
      :map evil-motion-state-map
      "L" nil)
```

Any clue why? should another mode be passed as :after?

`evil-motion-state-map` is only taking precedence in the treemacs buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:m` to map in `evil-motion-state-map`.

And also you don't the package name is evil not evil-mode.

So maybe like this.

```
(map! (:after evil
       :m "L" nil))
```